# How to make an interactive network plot using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I was wondering if it's possible to make an interactive network graph using the `igraph` package in R?

For example, if we were to make a very simple network like so:

```
library(igraph)

edgeWeight <- c(1,2,10,3,4)
edgeDir <- c(1,2, 1,3, 1,4, 1,5, 2,3, 2,4, 2,5, 3,4, 3,5, 4,5)

net.xy <- make_graph(edgeDir, 5, directed = F)

E(net.xy)$width <- edgeWeight

plot(net.xy)
```

The plot would look something like this:
[image: Network Graph]

What I'm wondering, is there any way to make the plot interact-able? Specifically, I'm trying to achieve something just like the function in the `plotly` library where the user hovers the mouse over, say, the nodes or edges and a box appears containing information.

For example, if the user hovered the mouse over a particular edge, a box displaying the edge weight would appear.

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this... or is it even possible using the `igraph` package?

Comment: i haven't tried igraph on plot_ly before (https://plot.ly/r/network-graphs/) but i guess it should be do-able?

Comment: interesting. Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: You might try `tkplot`.  After you plot with `tkplot(net.xy)` right click on an edge to see it's width.

Comment: I'm just trying ```tkplot``` right now... I see that even in the ```tkplot``` documentation it says to right-click on something to show information. However, when I right-click, it's selecting the edge, but no information is shown. Same with the nodes. Am I missing something obvious?